# Join Results in duplication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. I suppose to get the result into one row, but when i try with the below query it results duplication.

Query:

```
Select OrgaID, UnitID, LeaveTitle, NoOfFromService, NoOfToService, 
EmpType.EmployeeTypeName, IsExpatriate,
(ALR.LeaveTypeShortName + '(' + convert(varchar,ALR.NoofDays) + ') | ' + 
MLR.LeaveTypeShortName + '(' + convert(varchar,MLR.NoofDays) + ') | ') 
Leaves
From LeaveCategory LvCat    
Left Join (Select LeaveCategoryID, LeaveTypeShortName, NoofDays From 
LeaveEntitledEntry Where LeaveTypeShortName = 'AL' ) ALR On 
ALR.LeaveCategoryId = LvCat.Id
Left Join (Select LeaveCategoryID, LeaveTypeShortName, NoofDays From 
LeaveEntitledEntry Where LeaveTypeShortName = 'MDL' ) MLR On 
ALR.LeaveCategoryId = LvCat.Id
Where OrgaID = @OrgaID and LvCat.Status = 1
```

For Reference :

Table 1: (LeaveCategory)
   [image]

Table 2: (LeaveEntitledEntry)

[image]

Result :

[image]

So how can i change my joins to achieve expected result. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation to access the two types of leave data by using a join to a single subquery.  The reason this trick might work is that allows us to generate a single record for each `LeaveCategoryID`, along with its `NoofDays` values for both the `AL` and `MDL` types.  This means that we can do with just a single join, which should avoid the duplication problem you were having.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        LeaveCategoryID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeShortName = 'AL'  THEN NoofDays END) AS NoofDaysAL,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeShortName = 'MDL' THEN NoofDays END) AS NoofDaysMDL
    FROM LeaveEntitledEntry
    GROUP BY LeaveCategoryID
)

SELECT
    OrgaID,
    UnitID,
    LeaveTitle,
    NoOfFromService,
    NoOfToService,
    EmpType.EmployeeTypeName,
    IsExpatriate,
    'AL('  + CONVERT(varchar, t.NoofDaysAL)   + ') | ' +
    'MDL(' + CONVERT(varchar, t. NoofDaysMDL) + ') | ') AS Leaves
FROM LeaveCategory LvCat    
LEFT JOIN cte t
    ON LvCat.Id = t.LeaveCategoryID
WHERE
    OrgaID = @OrgaID AND
    LvCat.Status = 1;
```